# Using VALUE within cell reference

Tags: excel

So to simplify the problem:

I have two worksheets within a workbook, `Alpha` and `Beta`.

I need to reference a particular value in a cell in `Alpha` to select a cell in `Beta`, i.e.:
If the value of `B2` in `Alpha` = `76`, then I need to reference cells in row `76`.

I'm no wizard, but I've tried: `=Beta!(H(VALUE(Alpha!B2)))`

(In the above example my end goal is referencing H76 in Beta)

I know this isn't correct but I think it gives a better idea of what I'm trying to do.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for the bad tags, I'm new to this.

Comment: please make an effort to properly format your questions and to use more accurate tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you could use the [INDIRECT function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx) to create the reference based on the value of the other cell.

The following would create a reference to the column H of worksheet `Beta`, and the row would be specified by the value in `Alpha!B2`

```
=INDIRECT("'Beta'!H"&VALUE(Alpha!B2))
```

The above produces a reference that would be the equivalent of:

```
Beta!H[row_number_specified_by:Alpha!B2]
```

For example let's assume that: `=VALUE(Alpha!B2)` produces the result `76`
Then the original formula above would be equivalent to:

```
Beta!H76
```

Which based on the scenario description in the question is what you wanted..

Comment: I'm not sure if that applies, Ultimately I think what I'm trying to ask is can I perform a function within the cell reference i.e. call column H and row (value(x))?

Comment: can you give a more concise example? I'm not sure what you mean by "perform a function within the cell reference", or "call column H". What does "calling a column" mean?

Comment: Can I then use that reference to call reference on a different worksheet i.e. =Beta!INDIRECT("H"&VALUE(Alpha!B2))

Comment: yes. That's exactly what my example does.. Please try it out! But notice that it's not `=Beta!INDIRECT(..` but rather `=INDIRECT("'Beta'!..`

Comment: Ok that's exactly the problem I was running into. I knida knew what I needed to do but not how to format it. Perfect! Thanks for all your help Miky!